# fastest way to detect if string contains specific chars

Tags: java, regex, string, performance

I'm building an XML parser that goes over a big XML file and I'm looking for the fastest way to detect if a string contains a char(that isn't a `" "`, `"\n"` or `"\r"`). I've tried using regex but it is too slow and heavy. Another method I tried was to get the ASCII number of `" "`, `"\n"` and `"\r"` and to reduce it from the size of the String, if it's larger then there's at least one char. This operation is also heavy. Good advice would be appreciated.

Edit - Clarification:

Too slow is 300 milliseconds for a line of XML parsing + string manipulation.

Examples to the 2 ways I implemented:

By Redex:

```
if (!str.matches(".*\\w.*")
{
  // str that doesn't contains chars
}
```

By summing up ASCII values:

```
if (numOfWhitespaces + numOfSpecialChars >= str.length()) // +1 for ending /r in
  str
{
    // str that doesn't contains chars
}
```

The first solution(Regex) is slower in 200 milliseconds.
On a file with 500+ lines (where each line is being processed independently) it's crucial.

I hope it's clear enough. thanks!

Comment: By `/n` do you mean `\n`?

Comment: You question is very confused, it isn't clear what you really need to cound/found/detect. Describe it more specifically.

Comment: XML parsers already exist.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: show your code.  explain what "too" slow means.  did you pre-compile your regex and re-use that, or did you compile each time?

Comment: Iterate through the chars of string and if you find the character,break.Worst case complexity will be still n,where n is length of string.However, average case time complexity is less

Comment: I can't imagine a reason why you would need that when you build an XML parser. Maybe you have a wrong approach.

Comment: use algorithm and build your own. Alway work but not easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way to scan a String is with a SAX listener

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    for(int i=start, end = start+ length; i < end; i++) {
       if(ch[i] <= ' ') {
          // check if it is a white space
       }
    }
}
```

If you are not use a SAX parse or an event driven parser, this could be your performance bottleneck.